# rename a file in php on a windows file server (unc path)

Tags: php, copy, rename, unc, windows-share

In PHP I want to rename (move/copy) a file on a windows file server: 
    "\myserver\folder1\folder2\myfile.pdf"
to
    "\myserver\folder1\folder2\OLD\myfile.pdf"

(all folders already exist and destination file does not exist)

I tried this:

```
copy("\\\\myserver\\folder1\\folder2\\myfile.pdf", "\\\\myserver\\folder1\\folder2\\OLD\\myfile.pdf");
```

and

```
copy("//myserver/folder1/folder2/myfile.pdf", "//myserver/folder1/folder2/OLD/myfile.pdf");
```

I receive:

```
[function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The computer I am on / user logged in as has permissions to rename/move/delete/copy to that share/folder.

I am guessing I need to somehow give php permissions, or run php as my user?  OR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will be running as whatever user your web server runs as.  You would need to grant permissions on that folder to whatever user account that is.

Comment: that makes sense, but could I change the apache windows service to run as a different user other than 'local system' (and that user has permission) , OR ?

Comment: @Scott - yes, it would make sense to have apache run as a different user.  It would probably need to be a domain account as well to ensure that it can be given access to resources on the other server.

Comment: @Scott - an alternate solution might be to use FTP instead of a file copy, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Copy... use move_uploaded instead

This is one example getting the image from a form:

```
$img = 'sample.jpg;
$path = '//nameofyourpcinyournetwork/sharedfolder/folderyoulike/';
$pathwithimg = $path.$img;
if (!is_dir($path)) {
  mkdir($path, 0644, TRUE); // TRUE for make it recursive
}
if (file_exists($pathwithimg)) {
 unlink($pathwithimg);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $pathwithimg);
 chmod($pathwithimg, 0644);
}
```

Change safe_mod to Off if you have it On

P.D. Yeah i know, this post is 5 years ago... but no one said a valid answer and other people (like me) may find this question